# VSE: How do you precisely position two video strips

Tags: video-sequence-editor, edit-mode, video

How do you precisely position one video strip to another one?

Answer (score 8):

grab one strip, and move it towards the other while pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>: it will "snap" to the other strip's end even if it is on another slot:

[image]

Comment: This also works in the opposite direction - to align the end of a strip with the start of another.

Answer (score 3):

Drop one strip on top of the other. As they overlap, the strip will be outlined in red, dropping the strip will then snap the strip to the frame after the other strip.

[image: align a strip to the end of another]

This also works the other way - drop an earlier strip on the beginning of a strip and the end will snap to the beginning of the strip.

[image: align a strip to the start of another]

If you then want the strip to be in another channel, you can change the channel in the strip properties or use <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> to move the strip to another channel without changing its start frame.

Answer (score 1):

Use the snap tool. Hotkey: [**Shift + S**]

Select the strip you want to move to specific frame. Enter the frame number in the Timeline and Snap!

Comment: in other words, shift+S will snap the strip to the _cursor_ (the green bar reflecting the current frame in the VSE timeline)

Comment: Beware that you cannot snap (shift-S) more than one group of strips at a time. If they are in orderwhen you start they will all try to occupy the same frame, thereby stacking the strips on top of each other. You can place them in a meta-strip first, then snap them to frame, however performing an Un-meta function will reverse the various strip's stack or channel order.